# MCH5003, scalar error - ILE RPG

Tags: pointers, memory-leaks, ibm-midrange, rpgle

Called program entry:

```
dcl-pi PGM1;
  choice uns(3) const;
  returnCode likeds(returnCodeTpl);
  parameterPtr pointer const options(*nopass);
  parameterPtr2 pointer const options(*nopass);
  parameterPtr3 pointer const options(*nopass);
end-pi;
```

Caller program:

```
document.field1 = 'EL';
document.field2 = 'T';
document.field3 = 2780;

PGM1(1:returnCode:%addr(document));
```

`document` definition (*on called*):

```
dcl-ds document_ qualified based(parameterPtr);
  field1 char(2);
  field2 char(1);
  field3 packed(7:0);
end-ds;
```

`document` definition (*on caller*):

```
dcl-ds document qualified inz;
  field1 char(2);
  field2 char(1);
  field3 packed(7:0);
end-ds;
```

Called program then process the `document` DS, calling an exported procedure:

```
select;
  ...
  when (1 = choice);
    myProc(document_);
  ...
endsl;
```

`myProc` definition:

```
dcl-proc myProc export;

  dcl-pi *n ind;
    document likeds(document_) const;
  end-pi;

  dcl-s i int(5) inz;

  exec sql                    <--- Error appears there
    select count(field1) into :i from myFile
    where
      field1 = :document.field1 and
      field2 = :document.field2 and
      field3 = :document.field3;

  ...

  return i > 0;

end-proc;
```

`myFile` fields equal in types `document` fields.

The error a keep getting is **MCH5003 - scalar error. The length of the invalid scalar operand is 128.** Debug stop over the `exec sql` clause.

I really can't figure out what it is!

Comment: I'm not really following your code...but why are you passing a pointer instead of the variable?  Not to mention your passing the pointer by reference...so you're actually passing a pointer to a pointer.

Comment: Ahhh @Charles ... Ask my boss. This program contains multiple procedures with different parameters, so I had to think of a way to handle them all. So, pointers and based variables.

Comment: Anyways, what should I clarify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end it was a parameter passing error.

Before the call to PGM1, another call to PGM2 was passing the second out of eight parameters as char(91) instead of char(500).

I didn't see it because it was defined as likeds(), and that DS was supposed to be 500 bytes long.

Thanks anyways @Charles.

Answer (score 1):

Where is `dcl-ds document_ qualified based(parameterPtr);` in relation to the PI for the caller?

I suspect you should be passing the pointer by value, not CONST reference...

```
dcl-pi PGM1;
  choice uns(3) const;
  returnCode likeds(returnCodeTpl);
  parameterPtr pointer VALUE options(*nopass);
  parameterPtr2 pointer VALUE options(*nopass);
  parameterPtr3 pointer VALUE options(*nopass);
end-pi;
```

But I still see no reason for messing with pointers..

**UPDATE**
I don't think you need 3 parms...you can have multiple `BASED(ptr)` variables defined using the same pointer.

```
dcl-pi PGM1;
  choice uns(3) const;
  returnCode likeds(returnCodeTpl);
  parameterPtr pointer VALUE options(*nopass);
end-pi;

dcl-ds doc1 likeds(doc1_t) based(ptr);
dcl-ds doc2 likeds(doc3_t) based(ptr);
dcl-ds doc3 likeds(doc3_t) based(ptr);

  ptr = parameterPtr;
  //all three DS are overlaying the same memory at this point
  // you have to make sure you only access the DS that corresponds to
  // the actual memory layout being used... 
  select;
    when (1 = choice);
      myProc(doc1);
    when (2 = choice);
      myProc2(doc2);
    when (1 = choice);
      myProc3(doc3);
   endsl;
```

Comment: PGM1 contains multiple "based" variables (some to the first pointer, some to the second, some to the third), and for each "choice" is able to use them by calling a specific procedure. By passing the pointer by value, isn't the program simply creating a copy of the pointer address?

Comment: Btw, found this topic quite interesting. https://archive.midrange.com/rpg400-l/200601/msg01022.html
Thanks for the insight!

Comment: Problem is I can't pass by value to an RPG program. That is valid only with procedures, @Charles

Comment: Yep, that's true....sorry...didn't click that you were dealing with a *PGM.